# Is this sentence correct?

Tags: commas, hyphenation

Sentence: My friendly but silly, creepy but inviting neighbor waited for me in the parking lot.

My concern was whether I needed some hyphens for the modifiers  in "friendly but silly" and "creepy but inviting."

Answer (score 1):

There is a technique where you **Germanise** a string of words, linking them with short hyphens. It's kind of a New Journalism trick borrowed from German, which commonly creates new words from other words; hence Germanise, but it works. A Germanised phrase is witty, smart, modern, and creative if you can pull it off;

'When I denied Kanye a bank loan, he gave me a **you-think-Stalin-was-tough-wait-till-I'm-finished-with-you** glare before flouncing out with his Gucci encrusted goons.'

The point is to create a new concept which doesn't exist in English, by ramming other words together. The tool you use to Germanise is the **hyphenated modifier**.

### Your example

There is no single word in English to describe someone who is both friendly and silly simultaneously (though there are a few close ones: goofy, perhaps?) so you created a word by Germanising.

This works most effectively if

- the two words are very different
- there is no existing single word that would suit

If you rearranged the words in your example to friendly-but-creepy, you'd create a dissonance that might better suit your purpose.

## note:

In one of the other answers, foul-smelling-cherry- cake is offered. In this example, the hyphens are redundant because there is no new or novel concept created. Foul smelling and foul-smelling are identical. Germanising those two words doesn't create a new idea or concept that didn't exist already.

Comment: I wish you would add a reference for this technique.  Also, perhaps add that it is not advisable for people who are not proficient in English.

Answer (score 0):

Compound adjectives are two or more words that together make an adjective. When they come directly before a noun, they’re known as compound modifiers and usually have a hyphen, like a “foul-smelling-cherry- cake.” 
 If the adjectives come after the noun,  they it looks don’t need a hyphen at all.For example

The new metal is  rust proof.
Hope I do make sense.